# Python how do I auto generate a non existent primary key every time I insert new data

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, web-scraping

I have this SQL query, but I have to change the id everytime I insert new data, because It's a primary key. How can I make it add a new nonused primary key value everytime I insert?

I am using Microsoft SQL server Studio

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

#Timestamp for undersøgelse
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Host info og IP
host = "www.rejseplanen.dk"
dest = socket.gethostbyname(host)
hdata = 'host',host,'IP:',dest


#Responseheader request
request = urllib.Request('http://rejseplanen.dk')
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36')
response = urllib.urlopen(request)
rdata = response.info()



#SQL Connection til local database
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-THV2IDL;'
                      'Database=host;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM host.dbo.hosts')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)

con.execute('INSERT INTO host.dbo.hosts (Id, ip, host, HSTS, HPKP, XContentTypeOptions, XFrameOptions, ContentSecurityPolicy, Xssprotection, Server, Timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
            (4123, host, dest, rdata['Strict-Transport-Security'], rdata['Public-Key-Pins'], rdata['X-Content-Type-Options'], rdata['X-Frame-Options'], rdata['Content-Security-Policy'], rdata['X-XSS-Protection'], rdata['Server'], timestamp))

con.commit()
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You let the database do it.  So, the host table should be defined as:

```
create table host (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    ip . . . 
);
```

Then you leave the value out of the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO host.dbo.hosts (ip, host, HSTS, HPKP, XContentTypeOptions, XFrameOptions, ContentSecurityPolicy, Xssprotection, Server, Timestamp)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

(Note that `id` is not in the column list.)